# problem with libnet install

Tags: ubuntu, libnet

when i install libnet by sudo apt-get install libnet1, the program can not find libnet.h and I also can not find it at /usr/local/include or /usr/include.
so i download the libnet and make it, but I get the errors

```
make -C lib/ lib
make[1]: Entering director `/home/liuqiang/workspace/libnet/lib'
gcc -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -g -I../include -Iinclude -DTARGET_LINUX   -c -o core/config.o core/config.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
core/config.c: In function ‘__libnet_internal__seek_section’:
core/config.c:87: error: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
core/config.c: In function ‘__libnet_internal__get_setting’:
core/config.c:111: error: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
make[1]: *** [core/config.o] error 1
make[1]:Leaving directory `/home/liuqiang/workspace/libnet/lib'
make: *** [lib] error 2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's always the same: you need the `libfoo-dev` package to **build** against source code from library *foo* as the `libfoo` package merely ensures you can **run** the code.

So here for `libnet1`: run `apt-get install libnet1-dev` and you should be good to roll along.

Comment: I think you are right!  I just forgot to add the "-dev" thank you for your remind.

Comment: No problem.  So please vote up and/or accept the answer, that's how it works here.